# snow texture isn't realistic as tutorial

Tags: shader-nodes

i am following a tutorial link below, i follow all the tutorial step and even copy the same nodes but the result is very different as shown on minute 10:19

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=393zz7KDa_c&t=619s

the tutorial is made in 2021, and now i'm using the new blender 3.00
i tried to upload the blend file but it's still too big even after i compress it

[image]

Comment: Cycles or Eevee? Could be that? Turn up the roughness on the snow to 1 and change the specular to 0. Add a bit of a noise texture over the top and add a displacement node.

Comment: Cycles, i did try switching between cycles and eevee nothing change much. i did try your suggestion of roughness and specular but not much of change as well. in the original node is already included the noise texture and displacement node, as i mention before all the node is even setup by the youtuber and i just copy it.